# Getting columns from SQL lite using variables

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to access a column an from SQLlite database, with the table being Units, and the column being Unit_ID, and am using the select command as such:

`c.execute('SELECT Unit_ID FROM Units')`

This code works as intended. What I'd like to do is allow this command to take a variable in place of the table, and have written the code below:

`c.execute('SELECT (?) FROM (?)',('Unit_ID','Units'))`

This code produces an error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error"

Of course I would eventually replaces the values in the parentheses to variables and not strings, but doing that also produces this error.

Why is this doing this? Don't the question marks simply place a variable.

Comment: The question mark is a bound parameter.  According to the [SQLite select specifiction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), bound parameters are not allowed in the column and table descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

Would this help?

```
x = "Unit_ID"
y = "Units"
c.execute(f"SELECT {x} FROM {y}")
```